# Call Class Method from other Class not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, navigation, browser

I'm trying to call methods from class "Form1" from an other class.
Here's my Code

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    public partial  class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("loaded");
            orders.ObjectForScripting = new ScriptInterface();
        }

        private void webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) { }
        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
    public class ScriptInterface
    {
        public void callMe(string currid)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(currid);
            // the following throws security error
            Form1.webBrowser2.Navigate("http://www.mywebpage.com/client/index.php?id="+currid);
        }
    }

}
```

INFO: I have 2 WebBorwsers. I'm catching events from webBrowser1 for updating webBrowser2.
My problem is, that i cannot call the webbrowser2 methods outside from Form1.

Any Ideas how i can solve this problem?

Comment: Mark them as `public` instead of `private`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your WebBrowser components are not static (this is a good thing), therefore you cannot refer to them directly off of Form1 as your code sample is attempting to do.  You must obtain a reference to a Form1 instance and then you can call methods on them so long as they are marked public.  Depending on your needs it is probably even better to just pass along a reference directly to your WebBrowser components

Perhaps something like this:

```
orders.ObjectForScripting = new ScriptInterface(this.webBrowser2);
```

...

```
public class ScriptInterface
{
    private WebBrowser _browser;

    public ScriptInterface(WebBrowser browser)
    {
        _browser = browser;
    }
    public void callMe(string currid)
    {
        _browser.Navigate("http://www.mywebpage.com/client/index.php?id="+currid);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Form1 in:

```
Form1.webBrowser2.Navigate(...)
```

Is not an object, but it is your type. You need to create an instance of your class, or if you prefer, create an object to be able to call it's method:

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.webBrowser2.Navigate(...)
```

On top, your method are flagged `private`, which mean they can only be call from inside your instanced. You should flag them `public` if you want other object to be able to call them.

```
public void webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) { ... }
```

Or if you don't want to create an instance, you can declare this method as being `static`

```
public static void webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) { ... }
```

But you won't be able to access the fields that this class define unless they are static too.